# How to remove Nginx server blocks in effect

Tags: docker, nginx, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

I had a Nginx in a container (on a Ubuntu host) and several server blocks defined. I was tweaking them and wanted to remove them all. But stopping the container and removing the container did not help. The rules I was testing with are still in effect.

Are Nginx configurations being applied to the host as well? How can I remove all the configurations and start from scratch?

Note: I had the conf.d folder mapped to a volume on the host. the configuration file is still available in it.

Comment: Can't it be just a browser cache? Can you try from the incognito window?

Comment: Are you maybe editing the file in the container?

Comment: @IvanShatsky It seems browser caching may have been the issue. However, I cannot say for sure since I got rid of the persistent conf file in the volume as well. but it did solve the issue. thanks!

Comment: @BeppeC no I was editing the file in the volume and it was properly mapped. and yes nginx was in a container. I don't have it installed in host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ivan Shatsky pointed out in the comments, it must have been the browser cache. However, I got rid of the persistent conf file in the volume as well and the nginx effects were gone.